# how to set image to view if after picking it from gallery, onCreate method is called and it alreay has a image to set at that view?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

I am trying to set a image to CircleImageView after picking it from onActivityResult.
But problem is that when that activity is created, it already has a method  in onCreate which is setting a image to that view. So, whenever i pick a image from gallery and return to that activity the image from oncreate  method is setting to that view.
what can i do so that when the activity start, first the onCreate method image is set to that view and after picking image , the picked image is set to that view.

My code:

```
 public class MentorProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


long fileSize;
public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 100;

@BindView(R.id.profile_image_mentor)
CircleImageView profileImageMentor;
@BindView(R.id.edit_image_mentor)
CircleImageView editImageMentor;
   ProgressBar pbMentor;
String name, email, userId, password, contact, mentor, imageUrl, bio, category, uriString,
        youtubeLink, facebookLink, instagramLink, twitterLink, extension;
String fileName, path, displayName, imageName;
LoginResponse loginResponse;
String videoViewLink = "https://smakerspace.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Video/";
Uri uri, uriSelectedImage, file1;
File myFile;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
ProgressDialog progressDoalog;

boolean isImageInit = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mentor_profile);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    pbMentor.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("Mentor")) {
        mentor = getIntent().getStringExtra("Mentor");
    }
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("MentorPassword")) {
        password = getIntent().getStringExtra("MentorPassword");
    }

    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("spMentor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    userId = sharedPreferences.getString("userIdMentor", "");

    getUserDetails(userId, password, mentor);



}


   public void getUserDetails(String userId, String password, String mentor) {
    pbMentor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    retrofit2.Call<LoginResponse> ourSupplierResponseCall = RestClient.getClient().
            verifyLogin(userId, password, mentor);
    ourSupplierResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                pbMentor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loginResponse = response.body();


                if (loginResponse.getError().booleanValue() == false) {


                    imageUrl = "https://smakerspace.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/upload/" + loginResponse.getUser().getProfilePic();
                    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(profileImageMentor);
                    isImageInit = true;


                } else {

                }

            } else {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            pbMentor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}


@OnClick({R.id.edit_image_mentor})
void onProfileImageClick() {
                if (!isImageInit) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onProfileImageClick:Image is initing, please wait 
                ");
                return;
            }
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {

                        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        pickIntent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE);


                    }

                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        showSettingsDialog();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
        uri = data.getData();
        uriString = uri.toString();
    loadProfile(uriString);
    }
}


private void loadProfile(String url) {

    Picasso.get().load(url).into(profileImageMentor);
    profileImageMentor.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));


}

private MentorProfileActivity getActivity() {
    return MentorProfileActivity.this;
}
```

}

The image sets for few seconds and then the previous image is setted again.

Answer (score 0):

could try to add a boolean flag isImageInit in the code:

```
    boolean isImageInit = false;
    public void getUserDetails(String userId, String password, String mentor) {
        pbMentor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        retrofit2.Call<LoginResponse> ourSupplierResponseCall = RestClient.getClient().
                verifyLogin(userId, password, mentor);
        ourSupplierResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    pbMentor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    loginResponse = response.body();
                    
                    if (loginResponse.getError().booleanValue() == false) {
                        imageUrl = "https://smakerspace.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/upload/" + loginResponse.getUser().getProfilePic();
                        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(profileImageMentor);
                        isImageInit = true;
                    } else {}
                } else {}
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                pbMentor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });}
    @OnClick({R.id.edit_image_mentor})
    void onProfileImageClick() {
        if(!isImageInit){
            Log.d(TAG, "onProfileImageClick:Image is initing, please wait ");
            return;
        }
        //... your old code
    }
```

Comment: still same problem, after image selecting it views and again the response image is displayed.

Comment: It's recommand that you check whether the click is allowed only after `isImageInit `displays the network image, set it to `true`, and you can update your modified code.

Comment: i have updated the code, please check it out if i am doing something wrong. @shirley